# Fixed positioned div to align right within absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, fixed, absolute

I have this `fixed` positioned button within a `absolute` positioned wrapper.
I would like to align the button within the wrapper but to the right.

Right now I can only align it center within the wrapper or left within the wrapper.

I know the `fixed` position breaks the flow, but I know it is possible to do this , I just can't figure out to get this working.

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="nav-container">
    <div id="logo-white">LOGO</div>

    <div class="menuButton">menu</div>


    </div>
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9v4o5sjo/)

Comment: No, that is not possible. Reference point for fixed positioning is always the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have pulled the .menuButton div from left and right both to 0 distance so **just remove left:0px;** and change position to position:absolute; in .menuButton

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9v4o5sjo/4/) : **UPDATED**

```
 .menuButton {
        height:35px;
        width: 35px;
        background: #39C;
        position: absolute; /* Changed from fixed */
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 25px;
        right: 0px;
        /*left: 0px; ---- REMOVED */
        margin: 0px auto;           
    }
```

Comment: I would like to have the button within the absolute positioned wrapper. In your example it seems like it is outside?

Comment: Now just check the updated answer, if still any problem feel free to ask.

Comment: now it doesn't seem to be fixed?
I need this button to be fixed,

Comment: actually not getting what you trying to say. You want that button on same position while scrolling of page? and if so then it will not be in .nav-container div. The .nav-container div will move up while the menu stays at mentioned fixed position

Comment: I would like the button to be fixed, but within .nav-container div area that has the green area. Placement of the button should be to the right.

Basically how your updated demo is, but just where the button has a fixed position.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes excatly what you describe. and the menu will be placed to the right

Comment: nope buddy, see do you want to stay button on right and should not go up while scroll? Or you also want that the green div should also remain at same place along with button?

Comment: Okay so I would have to pull out the button "Menu" and not have it within the nav-container?

Comment: Ya look 1) if you want it inside green div such that green div goes above on scroll then obviously menu will travel along that green div  2) If you want to stick and made displayed all time on screen at fixed right position than there are again two chances a) green div goes above on scroll while menu remains fixed OR b) green div and menu both stays but content of page will just move along like this [Demo 3](https://jsfiddle.net/9v4o5sjo/6/)

Comment: It is the option 2 a I would like.

Couldn't this be achieved with media querries, if no other option

Comment: Then this is the [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/9v4o5sjo/7/). You satisfied with the Answer?

Comment: I think we are back to where we started now.

With media querries i found the solution I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/9v4o5sjo/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution to align it right:

```
 .menuButton {
        height:35px;
        width: 35px;
        background: #39C;
        float:right;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 25px;      
    }
```

Comment: I can just see that you removed the fixed position.
The button needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cx1k0tje/)

```
     .menuButton {
        height:35px;
        width: 35px;
        background: #39C;
        position: fixed;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 25px;
        right: 0px;
        /*left: 0px; removed as its not necessary when right as 0 */
        margin: 0px auto;           
    }
```

I have removed left properties as its not necessary when right set as 0

Comment: I also got this far. I would to have the button aligned with the rest of the content, so is it possible to have the button placed to the right inside the green area of the nav-container and still have the button to be fixed?

Comment: If position is fixed. you cannot wrap the content with in the outer container. so its better to change it to relative. so that menu stays in the green area. Note: Position fixed will be always fixed to browser layout not the content layout so you cannot move menu within the container

Comment: I have tried to do this with media querries.
I now have it excatly as I want.

Is this a bad way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/9v4o5sjo/8/

Answer (score 0):

In this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9v4o5sjo/8/) I have the setup as I want it to be.

I have have used media queries to get the wanted output.

Please let me know if this is bad pratice?

```
 .menuButton {
        height:35px;
        width: 35px;
        background: #39C;
        position: fixed;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 25px;
        right: -890px;
        left: 0px;
        margin: 0px auto;   
        }

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
   .menuButton {
        right: 25px !important;
        margin: 0px;
        left:auto;
        }
}
```